# Proxy error when accessing jenkins

Tags: jenkins, apache2, continuous-integration

When i access jenkins i get this error-

Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.

Reason: Error reading from remote server

i tried the init script to restart jenkins but it fails saying 8080 is already in use. I changed the jenkins default port but i still get the above error. any pointers on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing: 
Stop the web server on which you are running jenkins. 
Run netstat -a.
Is port 8080 in use?
If it is, you will need to change the port of the web server to something other than 8080.  (9090 is easy to remember).

If 8080 is in use, you should have received an error when you tried to start up the web server.  Check the log for the web server.

Incidentally, did you really mean you changed the jenkins default port?  Or is this the default port of the web server to which jenkins is running?

Comment: Hi Kevin, This is the error message from apache logs - proxy: error reading status line from remote server 127.0.0.1:8080 and by changing the port means the default port of the web server to which jenkins is running

Comment: If you are running Apache by itself, it won't work.  Apache will need to be configured to something like Tomcat or JBoss.  If you decide to go this route, (let's assume tomcat), shut down Apache, start tomcat and copy jenkins.war to the tomcat\webapps folder.  Then try accessing localhost:8080\jenkins.  Getting apache and tomcat (or JBoss) working with Apache is probably in another thread on SO.